# Cant load model from Content in latest Monogame version

Tags: c#, monogame, visual-studio

Using *MonoGame 3.4,* I'm trying to display a simple textured basketball.

Within the Game1 class, I've created `Model mModel`. My `Initialize` function contains all the proper Matrix information. When I run the program, I get an error stating `ContentLoadException was unhandled` and `Could not load basketball02 asset as a non-content file!`

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    mModel = Content.Load<Model>("basketball02"); 
}
```

I used the MonoGame Pipeline application to build the required xnb files for the Content folder, but for some reason this error keeps popping up and `mModel` returns `null`. I've even changed the model's Build Action to `Content` and Output Directory to `Copy if newer` like other sites and forums suggested, but still got the same results. (VS2015)

Comment: Did you try setting the textureformat to "nochange"? It might have a fault in the texture, which causes the modelload to fail. This is because the Texture2D content processor is used for the embedded texture (so the error may actually originate from the texture failing to load and not the actual model xbn file).

Comment: @Felsir I just tried that and got the same error.

Comment: I got the ball to show. the ball was originally created in Maya, so I decided to see if it was a modelling problem and it turned out to the problem. I created the same model in Blender in the same file format and the model loads. So now I just have to compare Blender's export settings to Maya's (because I don't use Blender)